# vitejs / asset handling problem / targets wrong host during dev / CSS url not rewrited

Tags: vite

I'm using a java server for the backend and vitejs to build the frontend.

During the dev, this is my java backend hosted on localhost:8080 that includes css and js files provided by nodejs on localhost:3000 using npm run dev command

To illustrate my problem I am using the fontsource node_module. The css file provided by this package have a @font-face css instruction with a src attribute targeting a woff file.

The problem is that the url used for the src attribute  and rewrited by vitejs doesn't contain the host, consequently it is not found, the path is correct but it targets the wrong host : localhost:8000

I have used the "base" config option in the vite.config.js file so that all rewrited url contains 'http://localhost:3000' but unfortunately it doesn't work

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. In your vite.config.js add the `origin` option to the server block.

For example:

```
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        origin: 'https://vitejs.local.ddev.site:3000', // customise this to fit your needs
        port: 3000,
        strictPort: true,
    },
```

Relevant information:

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-origin
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12231#issuecomment-1448548337

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)